# ggplot trying to make a Cleveland plot but I cannot get a legend

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggthemes)

data <- read.csv('/Users/zbhay/Documents/r-data.csv', header = 1)

zb <- ggplot(data) +
  geom_segment( aes(x=x, xend=x, y=value1, yend=value2), color="black")+
  geom_point( aes(x=x, y=value1), color=rgb(0.2,0.7,0.1,1), size=4 )+
  geom_point( aes(x=x, y=value2), color=rgb(0.7,0.2,0.1,1), size=4 )+
  coord_flip() +
  theme_solarized() +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(0, 10000, by = 500) 
  )


zb + labs(title = "Title",
           subtitle = "subtitle") +
  xlab("Business Functions") +
  ylab("# of hours")

legend("left", c("Starting", "Ending"),
       box.col = "darkgreen"
)
```

Hello, here is the code. The CSV file is structured as follows; column A = names, column b = starting number, column c = final number.

I am trying to set up a legend that calls out the final number vs starting number. I have tried and tried but cannot seem to be able to crack it. If anyone knows a fix, I would appreciate it if you could let me know.

Comment: Could you please share some reproducible data using `dput`?

Comment: You need to pivot your data to long format so that the data in `value1` and `value2` are in a single column, with a second index column that defines whether the calue originally came from `value1` or `value2`.  Call the is new column `index`.  add `color=index` to your `aes()` call.  This works because it makes your data tidy.  ggplot2 and the rest of the tidyverse is designed to work with tidy data.  In its current form, yours is not.

Answer (score 0):

As a general rule when using ggplot2 you have to map on aesthetics if you want to get a legend, i.e. instead of setting the colors for your points as arguments map a value on the `color` aes, e.g. in my code below I map the constant value or category `start` on the `color` aes inside `aes()` for the first `geom_point`. Afterwards you could use `scale_color_manual` to assign your desired colors and labels to these "categories" or "values". Finally, the color of the legend box could be set via the `theme` option `legend.background`. However, the legend keys themselves have a background color too, which I set to `NA` via `legend.key`.

Using some fake random example data:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(ggthemes)

set.seed(123)

data <- data.frame(x = letters[1:5], value1 = runif(5, 0, 10000), value2 = runif(5, 0, 10000))

ggplot(data) +
  geom_segment(aes(x = x, xend = x, y = value1, yend = value2), color = "black") +
  geom_point(aes(x = x, y = value1, color = "start"), size = 4) +
  geom_point(aes(x = x, y = value2, color = "end"), size = 4) +
  coord_flip() +
  theme_solarized() +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(0, 10000, by = 500)) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c(start = rgb(0.2, 0.7, 0.1, 1), end = rgb(0.7, 0.2, 0.1, 1)), labels = c(start = "Starting", end = "Ending")) +
  labs(title = "Title", subtitle = "subtitle", x = "Business Functions", y = "# of hours", color = NULL) +
  theme(
    legend.key = element_rect(fill = NA),
    legend.background = element_rect(fill = "darkgreen")
  )
```

[image]